# Why does my page not change after I edit the page.vue in Wiki.js?

Tags: vue.js, themes, wiki.js

Iam currently trying to make a custom theme for Wiki.js. I have followed the instructions of the official documentation. I've created a custom theme in the themes folder of the client folder.
The problem is that the changes inside my theme are not showing up on the page.

I edited a bunch of different things but no matter what I did the site stayed the same. I've also tried editing the default theme but again nothing changed.

Comment: you builded using webpack and changed the theme settings?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable cache from your browser.
For example, on Google Chrome (right button mouse > Inspect > Network > Disable cache).
It works for me.